# java scp file using ganymed-ssh2 package

Tags: tomcat, noclassdeffounderror

I am using eclipse for development and I have included the package in the build path, but still I am getting this error.

```
HTTP Status 500 - 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Exception report

message 

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception


root cause 

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ch/ethz/ssh2/Connection
    Push_Individual_Engine.putFile(Push_Individual_Engine.java:107)
    Push_Individual_Engine.doPost(Push_Individual_Engine.java:80)
    Push_Individual_Engine.doGet(Push_Individual_Engine.java:47)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)


root cause 

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ch.ethz.ssh2.Connection
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1647)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1493)
    Push_Individual_Engine.putFile(Push_Individual_Engine.java:107)
    Push_Individual_Engine.doPost(Push_Individual_Engine.java:80)
    Push_Individual_Engine.doGet(Push_Individual_Engine.java:47)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)


note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.30 logs.


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Apache Tomcat/6.0.30
```

This is the code I am using,

```
private void putFile(File f){
        Connection Conn = null;
          try {


           Conn = new Connection("servername");
           ConnectionInfo info = Conn.connect();
           Conn.authenticateWithPassword("username" , "password");
           SCPClient SCP = new SCPClient(Conn);

           SCP.put(f.toString(), "foldername", "0755");
           Conn.close();
          } catch (Exception e) {
           try {
            Conn.close();
           } catch (Exception e1) {}
    }
    }
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The relevant jar file (the one containing the class which could not be found) needs to be put in the `WEB-INF/lib` directory of your webapp. It is not sufficient to simply add it to your build path.

Comment: thanks a lot mate...it helped me to get rid of the error, but when I am trying to run the servlet file (Which is doing scp operation), its prompting me with a "save the file" dialog box. Any ideas about this?!

Comment: I suggest you ask that as a new question.